# How to get user contacts from his office 365 account using Office 365 api using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, office365api

We are using Azure AD to authenticate and get the refreshed access token,We invoke below method to get Office 365 user Contacts

But when executing the above we are getting exception like "failed_to_acquire_token_silently"

Can anyone help that where we are doing wrong!

```
List<string> myContacts = new List<string>();

        var signInUserId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        var userObjectId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

        Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext authContext = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext(SettingsHelper.Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signInUserId));

        try
        {
            DiscoveryClient discClient = new DiscoveryClient(SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceEndpointUri,
                 async () =>
                 {
                     var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceResourceId,
                                                                                new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId,
                                                                                                     SettingsHelper.ClientSecret),
                                                                                new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserIdentifier(userObjectId,
                                                                                                   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

                     return authResult.AccessToken;
                 });

            var dcr = await discClient.DiscoverCapabilityAsync("Contacts");

            Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.OutlookServicesClient exClient = new Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.OutlookServicesClient(dcr.ServiceEndpointUri,
                async () =>
                {
                    var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceResourceId,
                                                                                new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId,
                                                                                                     SettingsHelper.ClientSecret),
                                                                                new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserIdentifier(userObjectId,
                                                                                                   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

                    return authResult.AccessToken;
                });

            var contactsResult = await exClient.Me.Contacts.ExecuteAsync();

            do
            {
                var contacts = contactsResult.CurrentPage;
                foreach (var contact in contacts)
                {
                    myContacts.Add(new MyContact { Name = contact.DisplayName });
                }

                contactsResult = await contactsResult.GetNextPageAsync();

            } while (contactsResult != null);
        }
        catch (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalException exception)
        {

            //handle token acquisition failure
            if (exception.ErrorCode == Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalError.FailedToAcquireTokenSilently)
            {
                authContext.TokenCache.Clear();

                //handle token acquisition failure
            }
        }

        return View(myContacts);
```

Thanks in advance